# Cannot connect to remote database using Java and Mariadb

Tags: java, netbeans, mariadb

I am 97% sure that I have set my java web application correctly but I still get an error which points to missing the Mariadb connector or something that is close to that. I have tried to fix it but to no avail... I have

- added the depencency for mariadb in `pom.xml` file *(shown in first image)*
- checked that the `.jar` file is there. *(shown in first image)*
- tried to clean and rebuild...

**Upon checking the *GlashFish Server* tab on run, I can read this :**

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver 
>   at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1580) 
>   at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430) 
>   ... and at least 20 more locations.

[image]

---

Here I am trying to print the result in console to see if my application managed to connect to the remote database server, but I get nothing since it seems to crash **before** at the line `Class.forName("com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");` which I have found to be the right syntax for mariadb jdbc on their [website](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/). To save you time, they are saying that this is the *legacy way* of doing this, but that it still works. I did try to remove all the parameters from the url connection to only the user and password in `getConnection();` line, but it still fails. Am I missing something?

*To avoid confusion in the screenshot, myddns.link is including :3306 so that is not the error.*

[image]

Comment: can you show ur pom.xml and r u deploying ur webapp as a fat jar??

Comment: @user7851946 I already posted the `pom.xml` file and I'm not sure what you are asking about the fat `.jar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

instead of

```
Class.forName("com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

The [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/) you linked even states it explicitly:

> Please note that the driver class provided by MariaDB Connector/J is
>   not com.mysql.jdbc.Driver but org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver!

Comment: Doh! Obviously it fixed it. I was trying to go from a mysql jdbc to mariadb so that is why I left the `com.` even though it wasn't intentional. Thanks!